# СИ методы в структурах

Tags: c, c++

Сделал структуру с методами. Оказалось, что методы в структурах в СИ не поддерживаются, а только в СИ++. Теперь надо изменить код. Хочу минимально изменить, вынес функции за структуру и передаю просто ссылку на структуру в эту функцию. Но тогда придётся к переменным дописывать "имя_переменной_структуры.", т.е. уже к элементу структуры нельзя обратится просто: "имя_переменной структуры", нужно дописывать перед этим объект структуры. В каком-то языке я видел, писали так: "use VAR" и переменный могли подгружаться сразу из VAR. В общем можно как то в начале определить чтобы не дописывать везде структуру? Или мне придётся писать так: "СТРУКТУРА.ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ"? 
**PS Почему-то не могу коментить**
Вот этот код почему то ошибку выдаёт:

> error C3861: funcG: идентификатор не найден 
> error C3861: funcF:идентификатор не найден 
> error C3861: funcY: идентификатор не найден

Вот в этом коде почему-то: http://pastebin.com/rEnWm2wh

Comment: @mctrane, не ленитесь, пишите всюду `stru.var` или `pstru->var`. Код всем будет понятней.

Comment: просто препод разозлил, сказал что мы изучаем СИ, а не СИ++. И мне 5 лаб теперь перепечатывать. Хотя я ему сказал что понял и в след раз учту. Хотел показать ему,  что даже код почти не изменится. Вот почему бы не засчитать, с условием того, что структуры у нас будут ещё очень далеко.

Comment: @mctrane Так он ещё требует, чтобы задания выполняли на том языке, который изучаете? Вот сволочь!

Comment: @mctrane, покажи код, того что ты уже сделал, так легче будет сориентироваться - где и как ты указываещ "имя_переменной_структуры."

Comment: @alexlz, ага, хотя дисцплина называется "Языки программирования". Вообще по идее на каком хочу, на таком и должен делать. Ну я вообще не вижу смысла в СИ. Он не пригодится. В шарагах у нас и то лучше. Изучают СИ++ и всё ребята там понимают. У меня то слава богу есть опыт, а остальные из группы ничего не понимают, потому что препод вообще не компитентен.  

@derkode, фиг с ним, уже добавил имя структуры к переменным, спасибо)

Comment: да мне пофиг) А что, в СИ нельзя вызывать функцию в функции? Вот апдейтил, код почему-то говорит, что funcG,funcY,FuncF - идентификатор не найден.

Comment: На Си или на  крестах пишут больше (в т.ч. *больших* программ) это тот еще вопрос. Уже написанного, работающего и постоянно поддерживаемого кода IMHO на Си как раз больше.

И есть разные мнения на чем стоит, а на чем не стоит писать новый код. Если интересно, можете ознакомиться с [мнением](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57918) одного довольно известного в мире IT человека.

Comment: @mctrane Что изменить? Где нибудь код можно увидеть целикосм? (Да, кстати, когда объявляете локальную структуру result, поле valid у неё по умолчанию будет true (это сколько?) или false? А то у Вас там функции в этом плане весьма странные)

@avp у Торвальдса идеи бывают весьма странные. Не знаю, как сейчас, а в прошлом он долго сопротивлялся идее завести репозиторий в какой-нибудь системе контроля версий для ядра. Дошло до того, что одна фирма держала левый репозиторий в своей системе на своём сервере (фирму не помню, чего-то там bit...)

Comment: > И мне 5 лаб теперь перепечатывать

Никогда не понимал эту маниакально-маразматическую любовь преподов к распечатанным лабораторным/курсовым. Всегда, еще учась в институте, задавался вопросом, чем же их не устраивает лабораторная, принесенная на флешке в виде сосбтвенно кода и пояснительной записки в электронном виде? Почему нужно именно распечатывать? Неужели удобнее читать код с этих листков, которых студенты приносят под несколько сотен в общей сложности?

Comment: @alexlz, [RMS](http://stallman.org/stallman-computing.html) тоже писал:

     I find C++ quite ugly.

Comment: @avp Это который "известный взломщик Ричард Столлман"? ((c) "Криминальная Россия" -- был такой сериал). Он много чего писал (пишет?). Про то, как книгу почитать...

Кстати, посмотрите в инете историю одной священной войны -- "RMS против tcl'а". Так что там не только C++.

@DreamChild бумагой, пропущенной через шредер, хорошо на зиму малину прикрывать в саду (говорят).

Comment: @alexlz ну тогда многое становится ясно))

Comment: @mctrane некоторые правки внёс, так что у меня компилится. Отмечены комментариями. Но разбираться -- не разбирался. Ошибки там быть должны. (Кстати, C++ к синтаксису построже будет...) http://pastebin.com/T6RSjg4h

Ну и scanf_s у меня в gcc тоже не водится -- это MS-прибамбас.

Comment: @alexlz, почитал "RMS против tcl'а" ну,  так в результате он все же  оказался прав (конечно, Ousterhout tcl сам забросил).

--

Ради интереса "накликал" некоторую "статистику" по исходникам в пакетах из http://debian-counting.libresoft.es/  в SLOC. 

Top 3 -- всего 14715287 строк  C/C++ -- 6255304/5068343

Top10 -- 31124571 13182298/8924014

пакеты от 1000000 строк (35 шт.) -- всего 66154947 строк C/C++ -- 32331489/18437253

==

А тут я своим глазам не поверил. Первые 10 пакетов из 2-й тысячи (58635-58169 SLOC)

Total -- 583933 С -- 360905 С++ -- 80823

--

Вот такие пироги...

Comment: @mctrane, это

    Ну я вообще не вижу смысла в СИ. Он не пригодится.

Вы писали?

Еще не передумали?

Comment: Зря вы так на C. Очень хороший, логичный, эффективный язык, со своей простой, но элегантной философией. Попробуйте его выучить и почувствовать.

Comment: Да, я уже понял, что язык нужный, хороший. Типа для каких нибудь отдельных модулей для крупных проектов, да? Просто я люблю ООП, а в СИ его нету.

Comment: @mctrane: Угу. Но в C++ его, честно говоря, тоже практически нету :-) Хороший ООП-язык — Smalltalk. [Окей, окей, возьмите поправку на некоторую эпатажность.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё ясно, в СИ просто нужно объявлять функции перед их использованием, никак в Яве, например)) Всем спасибо)

Comment: Вывод неверный. В C++ -- да, в C -- необязательно. Только вот для необъявленной функции транслятор примет тип возвращаемого значения -- int.

Comment: ааа, блин, где можно почитать что где что можно, где нельзя. Чтобы не путаться. Эти 2 языка мне вообще не нравятся. СИ++ потому что его все обсирают, СИ из-за отсутсвия возможности ООП. И ещё в СИ нельзя объявить счётчик прямо в определении цикла.

Comment: @mctrane: несмотря на то, что можно: этим очень не рекомендуется пользоваться. Это фича оставлена для обратной совместимости с версиями C времён Очакова и покоренья Крыма, и она кроме WTF ничего вам не принесёт. Пользуйтесь предварительными объявлениями, они rulez.

Comment: Счетчик прямо в цикле

    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) ...

вот это?

Это запросто. Например:

    gcc -std=gnu99 ...

А ООП... 

Что именно Вас в этой концепции так привлекает?

Comment: @alexlz: и проведёт default promotion для параметров. Попробуйте скомпилировать такое:

    char c = 'A';
    int x = f(c);
    int f(char c) {}

(получится ошибка компоновки, по идее).

Comment: @avp, кайф получаю, когда получается система, отдельная, в отдельном файле, можно сказать API для кода)) Также Методы вызываешь через "." или "->", нравится код с этими символами. А ещё статические методы через "::"))

Comment: @VladD, с внутренней функцией, да, компилятор именно так ругается. А вот с внешней 

    int f(char c) {  }

обычный вызов gcc все делает нормально, а gcc -std=gnu99 ругается, но на стадии компиляции и просто на отсутствие декларации f().

Comment: @mctrane, ну, с раздельной компиляцией и вызовом функций по указателю

(в случае структуры с указателями на функции вызов будет как раз через операции "." или "->", которые Вам так нравятся)

в Си все нормально.

Хуже с обобщенным программированием (шаблоны) и автоматическим вызовом деструкторов.

Comment: @avp, да так и сделал)) Завтра буду возвышать СИ, чтобы препод поставил зачёт по лабам :) И впринципи врать не буду, если только преувеличивать) Это его любимый язык, СИ++ он ненавидет вообще, никогда ненависити к языку такой не видел)))Он меня обматерил за СИ++))

Comment: @avp можно и не -std=gnu99, а -std=c99.

@VladD ошибка при компиляции -- тип параметра не совпадает.

@mctrane нет ООП -- проблем меньше. А за что Вы её любите? ("Object-oriented programming generates a lot of what looks like work. P.Graham). @VladD и почему от Smalltalk'еров (как это на русском-то будет?) столько пены прёт? Аж до экстремального программирования.

@avp "С -- макроассемблер, который считает себя языком высокого уровня" :)

@mctrane 

      Он меня обматерил за СИ++))

На кафедру. Или в деканат. Там ему разъяснят насчет допустимой лексики в общении со студентами.

Comment: @mctrane, ну и страсти у вас там кипят!

А возвышать или принижать языки не стоит. Просто для одних вещей лучше подходит Си, а для других С++.

На эту тему есть известное высказывание:

[“Hablo latín con Dios, italiano con los músicos, español con las damas, francés en la corte, ingles con los caballos y alemán con los lacayos”](http://multilinguablog.com/2011/03/12/carlos-v/)

Испанского короля Карла пятого (впрочем, его частенько повторяли с разными вариациями и другие деятели).

@alexlz, вот про макроассемблер -- это точно. За что его и люблю.

Comment: @alexlz: Ну, почему же пена? Каждому патрону место в обойме хорошего программиста.

По поводу макроассемблера — это на самом деле всего лишь шутка с относительно большой долей правды. Например, где вы найдёте макроассемблер, который умеет инлайнить функции? Ну стандартная библиотека у C ничего так. И lex/yacc под него есть :-)

Comment: @VladD

      Каждому патрону место в обойме хорошего программиста.

Хм.

      А один пулемёт по своим стреляет (c) Попандопуло, х/ф "Свадьба в Малиновке".

Интересно, в фирме "Крайслер" мнение об XP поменялось, или нет? Всё-таки 13 лет прошло с закрытия C3...

Comment: @alexlz: ну, продолжая аналогию, каждый вид оружия хорош против своего противника. Зенитка не покатит против подводной лодки, а вот против самолётов вроде подойдёт. Не стоит догматично применять какую-то идею, всегда стоит воспользоваться мозгами.

Comment: @VladD ну насчёт зенитки против подводной лодки, это у Пикуля в "Реквиеме конвою PQ-17". Там как раз был эпизод, когда моряк-американец отпугнул из зенитки подводную лодку. А насчёт "пены" -- это скорее к Хазину, Григорьеву и их единомысленникам (но это уже не программирование, а экономика).